# Histogram equalization function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I'm trying to implement the histogram equalization using this code:

```
clc
A=input('please enter image adress','s');
Iimg=imread(A);
Iimg1=double(Iimg);
histi=imhist(Iimg);
mmax=max(Iimg1(:));
h=histi/numel(Iimg1)
cdf=cumsum(h)
cdf=cdf*double(mmax);
c=uint8(cdf);
subplot(1,3,1)
bar(c)
subplot(1,3,2)
imhist(Iimg)
subplot(1,3,3)
imhist(histeq(Iimg))
```

Is my code wrong?
I don't get expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I get this from your code:

[image]

What is wrong? unless your image is `rgb`, the code works (I used `cameraman`).

Comment: syntax is correct but histeq and my code is diffrent

Comment: Now I understand! Let me change the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

i find correct code for this and write here for others

```
clc
A=input('please enter image adress: ','s');
GIm=imread(A);
[x, y ,m]=size(GIm);
if m==3
    GIm=rgb2gray(GIm);
end
inf=whos('GIm');
Isize=0;
if inf.class=='uint8'
    Isize=256;
    else if inf.class=='uint68'
        Isize=65565;
        end
end
HIm=uint8(zeros(size(GIm,1),size(GIm,2)));
freq=zeros(256,1);
probf=zeros(256,1);
probc=zeros(256,1);
cum=zeros(256,1);
output=zeros(256,1);
freq=imhist(GIm);%histogram
sum=0;
no_bins=255;
probc=cumsum(freq)/numel(GIm);
output=round(probc*no_bins);
HIm(:)=output(GIm(:)+1);
%show
figure
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(GIm);
title('original image');
subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(HIm);
title('Image equalization');
subplot(2,2,3)
imhist(GIm);
title('origina');
subplot(2,2,4)
imhist(HIm);
title('histogram equalization');
figure
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(histeq(GIm));
title('matlab equalization');
subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(HIm);
title('my code equalization');
subplot(2,2,3)
imhist(histeq(GIm));
title('hist matlab eq');
subplot(2,2,4)
imhist(HIm);
title('hist my code eq');
figure
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(GIm);
title('origina');
subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(HIm);
title('Image equalization');
x=(1:Isize);
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(x,output);
title('transform function');
subplot(2,2,4)
plot(x,freq);
title('transform function');
```

Comment: This code gives the same output image as obtained by histeq(). But why the histogram of the images (produced by your code and the other produced by histeq()) are different. The one given by histeq() is more flat than yours. Anybody please help.