# Diiference between histograms

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

Please refer to the question here

[Histogram equalization function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560037/histogram-equalization-function)

Here I used the second program by abbas mahmudi to equalize the image.

It is showing a histogram of an equalized image which is equalized manually. But why is this histogram different from the one which is generated for an image which is equalized using histeq(). In the later case, we get a more flat histogram. Why is there such a difference.

Comment: I dont know why you guys are downgrading the question rather than answering it.

Comment: I answered your question and deleted my answer, I thought you were looking for an algorithm. Sorry for false notification.

Comment: No prob dear @Tony. You can help me now. It will be really helpful for me if you can clear my doubt. Thanks.

Comment: I undeleted the comment, I brought you an example of how histeq works.
You can compare it with your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have an image with 120 pixels, and 12 different gray scale colors.
Our goal is, to have first an equalized histogram, 120pixels / 12 colors = 10 pixels per color. How is done ?

With two pointers, we start moving on the different colors.
How is it done ?

Look at colors 0-1-2

- 3 pixels with color 0
- 3 pixels with color 1
- 3 pixels with color 2

They all go the column number 0 in the new histogram, in the new image, they all will have color 0.

Lets continue

- 4 pixels with color 3
- 3 pixels with color 4
- 1 pixel with color 5

All these 9 pixels will have in the new image, grayscale value 1.
However, in the equalized histogram, there should be 10 pixels foreach color, we still miss one. We will take this one pixel from the 6th column in the old histogram.

Lets continue
19 pixels remained with color 6, 10 of them will fill the 3rd column in the new histogram, we will have 9 pixels left. They will go to the fourth column.

At which column we finished all the 20 pixels of the 6th column in the original histogram ? in the fourth column in the new histogram. Hence, all the 20 pixels will have the new grayscale color number 3 (n-1).

**Here is the histeq algorithm**

[image]

- **H(K) specifies the # of pixels with gray-value K**

[image]

**Now, to make it easier for you, look at this example:**

[image]

[image]

**Taken from the IP course slices that I'm learning.**

Comment: Not able to understand it ..Can you please share some link or can you explain bit more.

Comment: An edit has been done. I've explained some of the process.